# How to Extract a substring from a flowfile Name in NIFI

Tags: javascript, apache-nifi

I have a file called 'test.abcde.houses.csv' and I want to extract the substring 'abcde' which I will use in my next processor group to query the database.

Currently, I am using the updateAttribute Processor group to try to extract the substring.

[image: UpdateAttribute]

This is the code I am using in the value section.

```
var userPattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('(.+?)\.[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{7,9}\..+');
var userMatcher = userPattern.matcher(fileName);
var matchExists = userMatcher.matches();



var user;
var userRemove;



if (matchExists) {
user = userMatcher.group(1);
userRemove = user + ".";
}
else {
throw 'Unable to parse username from file metadata.';
}
```

Question:

1. Is this the right way to extract a substring from a flow file name in NIFI?
2. Am I using the right processor group?
3. Does this code work with Nifi?

Comment: You have to use nifi expression language in values that are supporting expressions https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html JavaScript you could use only in ExecuteScript processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use NiFi Expression Language, a kind of NiFi's own scripting feature which provides the ability to reference attributes, compare them to other values, and manipulate their values. Please refer to this [official documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html).

`UpdateAttribute` processor is used to update/derive new/delete attributes. So you need to use the Expression Language inside `UpdateAttribute` to manipulate attributes.

Example:

`test.abcde.houses.csv` - this is your filename and if you want to extract `abcde` string from filename then you can use `getDelimitedField` function (Expression Language string function) like below. If the expression did not evaluate, then `user` attribute will be having `empty/null` value.

Property: `user` (if already present then update/assign value, otherwise create new attribute)

Value: `${filename:getDelimitedField(2, '.')}` (`abcde` is at second index/position in `filename` attribute value)

Expression Language has Boolean, Conditional, String Manipulation, etc. functions, so you can easily replicate your JS logic into `UpdateAttribute` to derive desired attribute value.

Comment: Thank you. I am still new to NIFI and only learned yesterday it has its own language.

Comment: If the answer has resolved your problem, then accept it as an answer. Thank you.